# Example of using multiple transactions with same session

Tags: java, hibernate

I am fairly new to Hibernate. I am trying to understand sessions and transactions using the example below.
I have an event management system. I have an entity called Event, and a user can edit an Event. 
Should I save a session as an instance variable in the service class and use it to do multiple
Transactions in different methods ? I also would like to use it as  a cache. 
Where should session object be stored ? Or how to best achieve what I am trying to do
below - I have two transactions - first will fetch as event object and second needs to edit it and save it to the 
database.

```
 ServiceClass {

     Session session ;

     Constructor () { 
         session = sessionFactory.getSession();
     }


     //First transaction

     public Event getEvent() {

        begin new Transaction on session.
           Fetch new Event object 
        End new transacton

        return event; //to display to user
     }

     //Second transaction 

     public void editEvent(String newName, Date newDate) { 

         begin Transaction
           Obtain the Event object from the session which was result of First transaction above
           event.setName(newName);   //This should be in persistent state and affect the database
           event.setDate(newDate);     
         end Transaction
      }


 }
```

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the session the transaction.   If your ServiceClass is used in multi-threaded environment (such as Servlets) then specifying it in a field will cause threading issues.  To avoid this problem, put the session creation in the editEvent() method, which should:

1. Create the session
2. Start transaction
3. Retrieve entities from database via session
4. Make changes to the entities
5. Commit transaction

Comment: Yes and also it is bad performance wise. So if I create a new session inside the editEvent() method, I will have to do new database fetch, right ?  How will I get the same object that was cached in the previous transaction, in session (in first fetch transaction here) as the session object would be different now? -- Thank you

Comment: Oh, you are wanting detached entities.  For hibernate you need to merge that entity back into the session.  See https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I also researched a little bit on session scopes in Hibernate ... and read that session-per-request is more commonly used...as you explained!  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#d5e737